# AWS S3 C# : Get all objects of particular Tag under a folder

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I get list of all objects which have a particular Tag in AWS S3? There is one API which returns all Tags associated with one Object. But I need a way to get all objects which have a particular tag. 
I am using C# sdk.

Answer (score -1):

In JS you can use

```
s3.makeUnauthenticatedRequest('listObjects', scope.params, this.cb);
```

to get all objects in a s3 bucket.
Use the method below and use prefix to specify tag

```
listResponse = client.ListObjects(listRequest);
```

Comment: Will it return list of Objects of a particular Tag? Or just all Objects under a Prefix?

Comment: How can we use prefix to specify tag?